# How do I add workloads for Visual Studio Offline Installer which is already downloaded in my computer?

Tags: visual-studio

I have downloaded Visual Studio Offline Installer following Microsoft Documentation:
[Visual Studio Offline Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

It is saved in my computer in **d:\vs**. This is the command I used to download all Web workloads:

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vslayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop
```

now I want to add this workload to be included offline in my Visual Studio Folder: ***Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools***
So how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
vs_community.exe --layout d:\vs --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools --includeRecommended --lang en-US
```